# Break statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Below is snippet of code for breaking the Execution of statement using `break` statement

```
 for(st=1;st<=20;st=st+5) {
    if(st == 15) {
       break;
    }
    document.write(st+"<br>");
 }
```

output comes

1-6-11-16

I don't understand why **16** appear as loop should break on **15**..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `st` NEVER hits `15`, so the if() never triggers. You probably want `if (st >= 15)` instead, so you can check for "15 or larger".

```
iteration #1: st = 1       st == 15 -> false
iteration #2: st = 6       st == 15 -> false
iteration #3: st = 11      st == 15 -> false
iteration #4: st = 16      st == 15 -> false
```

v.s.

```
iteration #1: st = 1       st >= 15 -> false
iteration #2: st = 6       st >= 15 -> false
iteration #3: st = 11      st >= 15 -> false
iteration #4: st = 16      st >= 15 -> true
```

Comment: plus1 for the iteration table

Answer (score 3):

Your value starts at `1`, not `0`. So you never hit `15` exactly.

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
for(st=1;st<=20;st=st+5){
if(st >= 15)
break;
else console.log(st);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement starts with 1 so it will never hit 15.If you want to hit 15 here you are

```
for(st=0;st<=20;st=st+5) {
    if(st == 15) {
       break;
    }
    document.write(st+"<br>");
 }
```